# creating a filled drop down list from phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, drop-down-menu

I need to create a filled drop down list which is linked to my table called called 'dog' in phpmyadmin. I need a user to be able to select a dog from the list and press search and the results show up. And all information be stored in my table in phpmyadmin. This is what I have so far:
It doest work its just an empty drop down and it does nothing. Please help.

```
<?php
   // set up connection parameters
$dbHost         = 'hostnamegoeshere';
$databaseName   = 'databasenamehere';
$username       = 'usernamehere';
$password       = 'passwordhere';

// make the database connection
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbHost;dbname=$databaseName;charset=utf8","$username", "$password");
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);   // enable error handling
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);           // turn off emulation mode

?>

//Return an error if bad connection
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ')'
        .$mysqli->connect_error);
}               
//query database for results
$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM 'dog'");         
?>

<h3> Search dogs</h3>
<select>
<?php
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
 $stmt->execute();
$res = $stmt->get_result();
while($dropdown = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
echo '<option value="' . $dropdown['dog'] . '"></option>';} ?>
</select>
```

I will be very grateful for any help

Answer (score 0):

Number of  issues in your CODE

> 1) Wrap off quotes form table name(`SELECT * FROM 'dog`')quotes
>
> 2) Don't use prepare and query at one time.(`$mysqli->query,$mysqli->prepare`)
>
> 3) Add text to your option(`<option value="value"></option>`)
>
> 4) You are mixing mysqli with pdo

You code would be

Create you connection with mysqli

```
$mysqli=mysqli_connect($dbHost,$username,$password,$databaseName);
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ')'
    .$mysqli->connect_error);
}



<h3> Search dogs</h3>
<select>
    <?php
    $stmt = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM dog");// wrap off and use only query to run
    $stmt->execute();
    $res = $stmt->get_result();
    while ($dropdown = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        echo '<option value="' . $dropdown['dog'] . '">'.$dropdown['dog'].'</option>';// add text to dropdown
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, I'm receiving the following message on the drop down page:                        //Return an error if bad connection if ($mysqli->connect_error) { die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ')' .$mysqli->connect_error); } //query database for results $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM 'dog'"); ?>                                   this is after using your code, thanks for that, however it still doesn't seem to work

Comment: Means you are not able to create connection with your database!!

Comment: Ahh you are mixing mysqli with pdo

Comment: thanks for all your help! thats got rid of those errors :) the actual drop down is still empty do you have any suggestions why its not bringing back the results from my phpmyadmin table?

Comment: Just use the code which i am providing and check what you get!!

Answer (score 0):

USE THIS

```
$res = $stmt->get_result();
$res =$res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)
foreach($res as $a){
echo '<option value="' . $a['dog'] . '">'. $a['dog'] .'</option>';} ?>
}
```

AT PLACE OF

```
$res = $stmt->get_result();
while($dropdown = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
echo '<option value="' . $dropdown['dog'] . '"></option>';} ?>
```